# What is causing sporadic error in SerialPort.Write under Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, serial-port, timeoutexception

I'm using a USB connection (FTDI) from Linux to an Arduino Nano under Mono.  This mostly works but after a while I get, at a seemingly random time, a TimeoutException attempting to Write to the SerialPort.  Apparently (see [the FIXME](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.IO.Ports/SerialPortStream.cs) and associated [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20348)), any error in Write will result in a TimeoutException, and there is no delay in timing, so I think it is fair to assume that it isn't actually a timeout, but just an error.

Mono code:

```
// FIXME: this reports every write error as timeout
if (write_serial (fd, buffer, offset, count, write_timeout) < 0)
    throw new TimeoutException("The operation has timed-out");
```

[Here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/b7a308f660de8174b64697a422abfc7315d07b8c/support/serial.c) (see write_serial) is the Mono wrapper being called, which appears to turn any error result from "poll" or "write" into a simple -1 error result.

Mono Helper:

```
int
write_serial (int fd, guchar *buffer, int offset, int count, int timeout)
{
    struct pollfd pinfo;
    guint32 n;

    pinfo.fd = fd;
    pinfo.events = POLLOUT;
    pinfo.revents = POLLOUT;

    n = count;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        ssize_t t;

        if (timeout != 0) {
            int c;

            while ((c = poll (&pinfo, 1, timeout)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
                ;
            if (c == -1)
                return -1;
        }       

        do {
            t = write (fd, buffer + offset, n);
        } while (t == -1 && errno == EINTR);

        if (t < 0)
            return -1;

        offset += t;
        n -= t; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've had no problems communicating from Windows/.NET to the same device and using the same write code (you'll see below).

This leaves me at a bit of a loss as to how to even diagnose this without writing some extensive C tests that I hope would reproduce the same IO patterns and timing as my current code does.  There are port sniffers, but that would merely capture the data, not diagnose and error.  Is there perhaps a way to catch and log IO errors in the Linux kernel?

My code is pretty straight forward.  Here is the relevant snippet:

```
    _port = new SerialPort(portName, Configuration.BaudRate);
    _port.NewLine = "\n";
    _port.ReadTimeout = Configuration.StartupCommandTimeout; // 7000ms
    _port.WriteTimeout = Configuration.StartupCommandTimeout;
    _port.Open();

    _port.WriteLine(command);
```

This always happens away from the main thread, though may not always occur on the same thread that the port was constructed, read from, and otherwise written to.

Using Mono version 3.2.8, though the code below is from Master as doesn't appeared to have changed.  I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on ARM.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your baud rate of that tty sent to?

Comment: @RubertN, 9600 N, 8, 1   Stuck to the defaults for the Arduino as they suffice for my needs.  Next I'm going to use a similar software stack, but a different board (RPi2 rather than Odroid XU4).  I nearly have that ready.

Comment: Ah..ok...not a speed issue...I used a lot of 32-bit ARM boards (i.e. STM32-FO, etc...) and never had a problem with the Mono serial stack at lower baud rates, but that was never on an Linux/ARM arch, x86_64 only. For high-speed tty (i.e. 567k+ baud/1.7uS, we had a 3rd-party C library that we used as Mono's serial.c is a total mess for non-blocking speeds like that...

Comment: $RobertN, So you built your own P/Invoke layer in Mono into a serial wrapping layer in C?  If I get desperate, I may try that, but it seems like an a lot of effort just to get a better error.

Comment: Yes, our p/invoke assembly on a 3rd party $$$ linux serial library, we were not going to write that from scratch, gotta hand-tuned c when you are talking 1uS serial times. Can you compile mono on your linux/arm setup or are you installing binary pkgs(?) as I might have some serial.c (and matching c#) updates you could try.

Comment: @RobertN, thanks for the offer; so far, the adjustment of thread priorities seems to be working.  If this turns out to be coincidental, perhaps I'll take you up on your generous offer.

Answer (score 0):

In my control system I have many threads executing simultaneously.  By giving increased thread priority (ThreadPriority.AboveNormal) to the actor (essentially thread) which services the serial port, I seem to have minimized or possibly eliminated the problem.  Perhaps Linux is more sensitive to serial port service starvation issues than Windows, or it is the varying hardware.